# Put each first column element the number of times that appear on second column

Tags: bash, awk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I don't have much experience using Unix tools and I was wondering how to do this:

I have a file with 2 columns like this (space tab):

```
Agent 2
Person 3
Place 1
Location 4
```

Each different element of first column will be a number (`Agent -> 1`, `Person -> 2`, `Place -> 3`, `Location -> 4`).

Thus, I want to have each first column numeric element the number of times that appear on the second column. In this case:

```
1
1
2
2
2
3
4
4
4
4
```

Explanation: `Agent (1)` appears 2 times, `Person (2)` appears 3 times, etc.

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ideal would be to start with number `1` and add a 1 for each different element in the first column. I would like it to do it automatically but I don't know how to do it :( , otherwise it could be done manually in any text editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=$2; i++) print NR}' file
1
1
2
2
2
3
4
4
4
4
```